# The SO Salary Calculator should have a GB Pounds option for London

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, company

I'm referring to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/company/salary/calculator

London's a location, and it would be useful for Londoners to see what this means for their pay. If it's just a flat USD -> GBP conversion, that would be reassuring to see; if it isn't it'd be useful to know what the pay really is for a Londoner.

Comment: "If it's just a flat USD -> GBP conversion". It isn't.

Comment: @Oded isn't this worthy of an answer? (and probably declining the request?)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - not my project, also not my call to decline it. It isn't as simple as that, and if we do add conversion, it will require explainin' (and I don't know the _exact_ rules, just the general one).

Comment: @Oded fair enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may add a conversion mechanism at some point in the future.

My understanding is that we take an *average* of the conversion rates of the past few years and apply that to get the amounts in GBP (or any other non USD currency).

Just putting a converter there without explaining where the value comes from would only cause confusion.

Comment: Cool, at your own pace. (Or theirs, I guess.) It just seems like an odd thing to leave missing for a company that has a London HQ which is even getting mentioned in that calculator.